# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn: how to update bound DataSource on property changed instead of on validation

Tags: winforms, binding, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I've got a BindingList binded as the data source of a DataGridView; one of the TSource properties is binded to a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn, but the data source is updated not when a click on the checkbox occurs, but when the focus on the checkbox itself is lost.

I know that something similar happens on a standard WindowsForms binding when the DataSourceUpdateMode is "OnValidation" instead of "OnPropertyChanged", but how can I have the same results with a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn?

The column is defined as follows:

```
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            column.DataPropertyName = "MyProperty";
            column.HeaderText = "Title";

            dataGridView.Columns.Add(column);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by handling the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event of the `DataGridView`.

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```