# Can I control when DataGridView reads and writes from/to its DataSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.0

I'm binding to a `List<MyCustomType>` and when I put a breakpoint on property getters in `MyCustomType`, they are seemingly being called repeatedly. What causes the `DataGridView` to automatically re-read the data and can I control this?

Secondly, I note that when I make changes to the data in the grid, these are not immediately replicated to the DataSource. Putting breakpoints on property setters in `MyCustomType`, they only seem to be called when I click outside the grid control. How can I make sure changes made in the GUI are immediately applied to the data source?

Comment: @Dylan no it's a regular WinForms project

Comment: @Mr.Boy Let me know if you have any question about the solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-reading from your properties is completely normal, it's because of rendering. When `DataGridView` renders cells, it reads from properties.

**Supporting [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx):**

If you want to changes on properties be visible to `DataGridView`, you should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to have two-way data-binding. This causes the changes in your objects immediately be visible in grid:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Category : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Properties
    private int _Id;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Id == value)
                return;
            _Id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Name == value)
                return;
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

- If you are using .Net 4.5, remove `[CallerMemberName]` and when calling `OnPropertyChanged` simply pass propert name, for example `OnPropertyChanged("Name")`

**Using [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx):**

To make changes to a list visible to the grid, for example when you add a new item to your list of data, use [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `List<T>`.

If you use `List<T>`, you should set the DataSource to null and again to your list to make changes visible to the grid.

```
BindingList<Category> source = new BindingList<Category>();

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load Data to BindingList
    new List<Category>()
    {
        new Category(){Id=1, Name= "Category 1"},
        new Category(){Id=2, Name= "Category 2"},
    }.ForEach(x=>list.Add(x));

    this.categoryDataGridView.DataSource = list;
}

private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Add data to BindingList 
    //Data will be visible to grid immediately
    list.Add(new Category(){Id=3, Name= "Category 3"});
}
```

- Also you can consider binding the `BindingList<T>` to a BindingSource and the the grid to `BindingSource`. It makes more sense when using designer.

**Using [CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx):**

Changes on `DataGridView` will automatically apply on your models OnValidating but as you also mentioned, you can use the [`CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the grid to commit changes to the data source.

```
private void categoryDataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (categoryDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        categoryDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

- I personally don't recommend such trick for all columns, for example suppose you have a string property that validates for minimum string length of 5, now how can you enter 5 character to it, then you will receive 5 validation error messages until you enter 5 characters.

Choose what you need carefully.

Comment: Thanks - but can I control when validation is done so my model is updated immediately? I am finding if I toggle a check-box, model is only updated when I click on a different cell for instance. I need what is visible to the user to _always_ represent the model the moment the user changes something.

Comment: I think this question my be the answer to #2 but I haven't tested yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468263/datagridviewcheckboxcolumn-how-to-update-bound-datasource-on-property-changed-i

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a compile error that `[CallerMemberName]` isn't known... do I need a specific `using` reference or version of .NET?

Comment: @Mr.Boy `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;` and .Net 4.5

Comment: @Mr.Boy if you are using .Net 4.0, simply remove that attribute and pass property name to method, for example `OnPropertyChanged("Name");`

Comment: Yeah, I was going to try that :) The problem I see is that `this.PropertyChanged` is always `null` - which says nobody is registered to this event? Is that because I use `List` instead of `BindingList` still?

Comment: @Mr.Boy `PropertyChanged` will be used internally in data binding mechanisms.

Comment: I tested, and changing to use `BindingList` made it all work now :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JeffBridgman thank you for editing typos and making the answer better :) hope you and other users find it more helpful now:)